# Why the http response is not displayed in network tab of chrome debug?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

I used postman to test my web service. In the http response body, I find the WS's response.

When I test my call, in my web application, using ajax, I can not find the response anymore. The tab contains a message saying "This request has no response data available."

this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: params,
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response); // no console here!
            console.log('response');
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("error");
        }

    });
```

Comment: When you use  the network tab sometimes you have to reload the page to get it right. This however can simply caused by a difference in your request from chrome and your request from postman. It is not always easy to spot if there is a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did but no it's not the cause. The console of response is empty too (in console tab)

Comment: have you checked the headers from postman to be the same as the headers from you ajax call in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

*Hi, Try like this.*

*In the ajax, you are passing params, it should contain something like action = get_pincodes.
while handling this, action = get_pincodes.
you must write echo json_encode($responce);exit;*

```
EX:

if($_REQUEST['action'] != "" && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'get_pincodes'){
    $responce = array();
    $responce[] = "500113";
    $responce[] = "500114"; // etc....

    echo json_encode($responce);exit;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe Adding charset=utf-8 to Content-Type in the response headers could solve the issue : Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: params,
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response); // no console here!
        console.log('response');
    },
    error:function(){
        console.log("error");
    }
```

});

Answer (score -2):

try to check if the XHR filter is selected and dont forget to reload the page afterwards [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did. The call is already exists but the same result is in the response tab (This request has no response data available)

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' is accepted but  'Accept': 'application/json' isn't. It stills Accept: */*

Comment: Yes I did, but it's not working! (please edit your code and remove the 
    "headers: {" just after url)